# Estimating phi for a time series in R with irregular time intervals

Tags: r, time-series

I've got timeseries data where multiple locations have been visited multiple times, and I need to check whether there's temporal autocorrelation in the data. I can use the corAR1 function in the lme4 library to construct and initialize the corstruct object, but no matter what starting value of phi I supply, it just spits the same value back at me. This seems to indicate that whatever method corAR1 is using to estimate phi isn't happy with my data.

Is there some other (easy) way to get an estimate of phi somehow?

Comment: if you provided a reproducible example you might get more help ...

Answer (score 2):

corAR1() is very unlikely to work with the lme4 package. It's from the nlme package. Have a look at corCAR1() or corExp() when working with irregular time series. And make sure that you specify the time variable correctly. E.g. corExp(form = ~ Time)